# Android Studio: Can't see layout preview while using DrawerLayout

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to use DrawerLayout to create Sidebar Navigation Drawer, but when I set DrawerLayout, in the preview it looks like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAHjF.png)

I'm using Android Studio 3.1.4
and those declarations:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tsahi.barshevsky.personalassistant"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Thanks.

Comment: In AS 3.2.1 preview works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have information by default android did not give preview, you have to launch your activity to see drawer layout.